# Installing a C++ application with setuptools

Tags: python, c++, cmake, wrapper

I have been trying figure out if what I'm attempting to do is even possible.  I have a C++ application dependency for my python package that I'm attempting to write.  Ideally, I would like to do "pip install X" and it would install the application as well as my python package.

This C++ application uses Cmake + SWIG and creates its own python wrapper that I'm linking up with.  I know, it's a wrapper of a wrapper, but I'm attempting to make this python wrapper easier to use.

Is there any way to "pip install" and magically build a cmake application?  Is my only option to create a python script that setuptools initiates on install?

Comment: distutils and setuptools provide their own build environment. If you want maximum compatibility you'll write a way to compile your app with that. You can't assume the user's system will have cmake or swig.